# Using Command Line (Linux) how do I enable the Bluetooth Adapter?

Tags: linux, command-line, bluetooth

I have 1 BlueTooth adapter on my laptop. Using the command line, I want to be able to enable / disable it.

This would be the same functionality that is achieved using GUI -> Bluetooth settings -> Bluetooth ON | OFF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

However, it seems to timeout sporadically. So needs some work...